# Big Difference in XIRR vs IRR calculation

Tags: excel, formula, irr, xirr

**Background**

I am getting substantially large variation in XIRR vs IRR calculations.

**Problem & Help requested**

Can someone please explain why I get two very different outcomes, and which method is more accurate? I've provided an example of cashflows which result in such large variation.

For this series of cashflows, the standard IRR function is returning -2.91% and the XIRR function is returning 0%.

If I change certain cashflows values I can get the values to align. For example

- If I changed the 31/12/2027 payment from -50,000 to 1, the IRR and XIRR align to -2.75%.
- or if I changed 31/12/23 payment from -300,000 to -400,000, XIRR and IRR align at -3.18%

I have no clue what is driving this delta. Any help be appreciated!

**Example Data**

```
Date    Cashflows
31/12/2023  -300000
31/12/2024  -300000
31/12/2025  -300000
31/12/2026  -300000
31/12/2027  -50000
31/12/2028  15000
31/12/2029  15000
31/12/2030  15000
31/12/2031  15000
31/12/2032  15000
31/12/2033  15000
31/12/2034  15000
31/12/2035  15000
31/12/2036  15000
31/12/2037  15000
31/12/2038  15000
31/12/2039  15000
31/12/2040  15000
31/12/2041  15000
31/12/2042  15000
31/12/2043  15000
31/12/2044  15000
31/12/2045  15000
31/12/2046  15000
31/12/2047  15000
31/12/2048  15000
31/12/2049  15000
31/12/2050  15000
31/12/2051  15000
31/12/2052  15000
31/12/2053  15000
31/12/2054  15000
31/12/2055  15000
31/12/2056  15000
31/12/2057  15000
31/12/2058  15000
31/12/2059  15000
31/12/2060  15000
31/12/2061  15000
31/12/2062  15000
31/12/2063  15000
31/12/2064  15000
31/12/2065  15000
31/12/2066  15000
31/12/2067  15000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found this [link](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/1205391-xirr-returns-zero-instead-of-a-negative-when-ending-value-is-less-than-total-contributions.html#:%7E:text=XIRR%20is%20returning%20a%200.00%25%20instead%20of%20a,that%20constant%20represents%20an%20error%20state%20in%20XIRR.) online which says I should enter in a guess for IRR

> If you format C3 as Scientific, you will see that XIRR returns about
> 2.98E-09, not really zero.
>
> Although you might think that is close enough to zero, in my
> experience, that constant represents an error state in XIRR.
>
> In this case, I believe it is an alternative for the #NUM error.
>
> Thus, XIRR might require a "guess" in order to determine the IRR.

After doing this, I've resolved my problem.

Comment: If you read the Excel help for IRR(), it informs you that if you don't include the "guess" argument it assumes 0.1 ie 10%

Comment: I often need to use a "guess" in XIRR when the returns are negative. The assumed `+10%` doesn't work well in that circumstance.